# Streaming bytestring as WAI HTTP server response body

Tags: haskell, bytestring, haskell-wai, haskell-warp, haskell-streaming

I have a value `body :: BS.ByteString (ResourceT IO) ()`, from a function based on [`BS.readFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-bytestring-0.1.6/docs/Data-ByteString-Streaming.html#v:readFile). I want to stream that value as the response body from a [Wai `Application`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.1.2/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Application). There's a helper, [`streamingResponse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-wai-0.1.1/docs/Network-Wai-Streaming.html#v:streamingResponse) that takes a value of the type `Stream (Of ByteString) IO r`. I'm able to convert my `BS.ByteString (ResourceT IO) ()` to `Stream (Of ByteString) (ResourceT IO) ()` through the use of [`BS.toChunks`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-bytestring-0.1.6/docs/Data-ByteString-Streaming.html#v:toChunks), but it contains an extra `ResourceT` monad layer. Passing the `body` to `streamingResponse` gives me:

```
Couldn't match type ‘ResourceT IO’ with ‘IO’
  Expected type: Stream (Of ByteString) IO ()
    Actual type: Stream (Of ByteString) (ResourceT IO) ()
```

I've tried various things like wrapping things in runResourceT, binding and hoisting values etc. but really have no idea how to proceed. [Here](https://github.com/anacrolix/transcoder/blob/228c8be10ac63d4f24569d847c8ed2d1a7f8da23/Main.hs#L200)'s the line in the full project if extra context is required.

## Update0

`hoist runResourceT body` seems to type check. Someone also referred me to a Haskell Pipes [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haskell-pipes/k1Vw18IWcrA), which may be a very related problem, and possible hint toward a solution.

Comment: `hoist runResourceT body` typechecks, but I don't think it will actually do what you want it to do. I suspect it will every "step" of the stream as an isolated resource context, with is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: Agreed. Pretty sure `runResourceT $ m >>= f` is not equivalent to `runResourceT m >>= runResourceT . f`, which is the property you need to apply `hoist`.

Comment: Yes I can confirm `hoist runResourceT body` does not work the way I intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to allow `Stream`s that live in `ResourceT`, we can do without the functions from [streaming-wai](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-wai-0.1.1/docs/Network-Wai-Streaming.html#v:streamingResponse) (that only work for `Stream`s based on `IO`) and instead build on top of functions like `responseStream` from [network-wai](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.0.4.0/docs/Network-Wai.html):

```
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
import           Network.Wai                     
import           Streaming                   
import qualified Streaming.Prelude               as S
import           Data.ByteString.Builder (byteString, Builder)

streamingResponseR :: Stream (Of ByteString) (ResourceT IO) r
                   -> Status
                   -> ResponseHeaders
                   -> Response
streamingResponseR stream status headers =
    responseStream status headers streamingBody
    where
    streamingBody writeBuilder flush =
        let writer a =
                do liftIO (writeBuilder (byteString a))
                    -- flushes for every produced bytestring, perhaps not optimal
                   liftIO flush
         in runResourceT $ void $ S.effects $ S.for stream writer
```

`streamingBody` has type [`StreamingBody`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.0.4.0/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:StreamingBody), which is actually a type synonym for a function `(Builder -> IO ()) -> IO () -> IO ()` that takes a write callback and a flush callback as parameters, and uses them to write the response using some source of data that is in scope. (Note that these callbacks *are provided by WAI*, not by the user.)

In our case, the source of data is a `Stream` that lives in `ResourceT`. We need to lift the write and flush callbacks (that live in `IO`) using `liftIO`, an also remember to invoke `runResourceT` to return a plain `IO` action at the end.

---

What if we wanted to flush the response *only* after the accumulated length of the emitted bytestrings reached some limit?

We would need a function (not implemented here) to create a division each time the limit is reached:

```
breaks' :: Monad m 
        => Int 
        -> Stream (Of ByteString) m r 
        -> Stream (Stream (Of ByteString) m) m r
breaks' breakSize = undefined
```

And then we could intercalate the flushing action between each group using [`intercalates`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Streaming.html#v:intercalates), before writing the stream:

```
streamingBodyFrom :: Stream (Of ByteString) (ResourceT IO) () 
                  -> Int 
                  -> StreamingBody
streamingBodyFrom stream breakSize writeBuilder flush =
    let writer a = liftIO (writeBuilder (byteString a))
        flusher = liftIO flush
        broken = breaks' breakSize stream
     in runResourceT . S.mapM_ writer . S.intercalates flusher $ broken
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [`readFile`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-bytestring-0.1.6/docs/Data-ByteString-Streaming.html#v:readFile), would [`withFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:withFile) + [`hSetBinaryMode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSetBinaryMode) +[`Data.ByteString.Streaming.fromHandle`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-bytestring-0.1.6/docs/Data-ByteString-Streaming.html#v:fromHandle) be enough?

`fromHandle` produces a `ByteString IO ()` that can be converted to a `Stream (Of ByteString) IO ()` that `streamingResponse` or `streamingBody` can accept.

There's the issue of where to put the `withFile` bracketing operation. According to the [WAI documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.0.4.0/docs/Network-Wai.html#t:Application), you can wrap with it the result of your `Application`-building function:

> Note that, since WAI 3.0, this type is structured in continuation
>   passing style to allow for proper safe resource handling. This was
>   handled in the past via other means (e.g., ResourceT).
>
> [...]
>
> In order to allocate resources in an exception-safe manner, you can
>   use the bracket pattern outside of the call to responseStream.

---

**Note:** the documentation of *streaming-bytestring* says that `fromHandle` closes the handle automatically when EOF is reached. Looking at the implementation, [that doesn't seem to be the case](https://github.com/haskell-streaming/streaming-bytestring/issues/9). You need `withFile` to properly close the handle.

Comment: Related to the topic of resource handling in WAI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517973/what-forces-drove-wai-application-to-be-redesigned-five-times

Comment: Hmm yeah, that would work, but I'm trying to maintain the body to be written behind an interface, I don't want any Handle type stuff leaking back across. Perhaps I could restructure the interface to return an action to allow embedding it in the bracket operation. [Here](https://github.com/anacrolix/transcoder/blob/e38d7b573a43e01b69d7618cbec3782792079b0e/Main.hs#L436)'s the interface for reference.

Comment: @MattJoiner Perhaps you could structure your interface in continuation-passing style, something like `OpId -> FileLength -> (BS.ByteString (ResourceT IO) () -> IO r) -> IO r`. That would hide the gory details of handle management from the user while still letting you employ bracketing operations. Packages like "managed" http://hackage.haskell.org/package/managed are built around this pattern. The alternative type `OpId -> FileLength -> (BS.ByteString (ResourceT IO) x -> IO (r,x) -> IO (r,x)` would force the user to exhaust the stream when consuming it.